# Docker & Django : Google Maps JavaScript API error

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to include Google Map into my django project using "Maps JavaScript API". I am able to successfully run in my local system when using the command

```
./manage.py runserver
```

and the "Google Map Platform API Checker" return's success like this 
[image]

but when I run in docker with the commands

```
docker-compose down 
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

and then check the the Google Map wont load and the "Google Map Platform API Checker" return's failure like this
[image]
any solution to this ?

Comment: how you are passing the key

Comment: by including local_settings.py file and loading it using django template language.

Comment: may be your docker contain pre existing settings file which is not updated